# Maximum level in The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance Tactics

Tags: the-dark-crystal-aor-tactics

Is there a level cap in [The Dark Crystal Age of Resistance Tactics](https://www.enmasse.com/games/darkcrystaltactics)? I thought I saw somewhere that it's 99, but I can't find it now. My characters are currently mostly level 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I saw 99 on [Collider](https://collider.com/dark-crystal-video-game-review/):

> I’m enjoying both leveling my characters (up to a max of 99!) and
>   experiencing the story as it unfolds.